# Rails: Ember.js Handlebar templates not being recognized

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a fairly basic question.

I am learning Ember.js to be used with a Rails backend.  I can get things to work when templates are mentioned inline in the HTML file.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
            <table class='table'>
                <thead>
                <tr><th>Recent Posts</th></tr>
                </thead>
                {{#each item in model}}
                    <tr><td>
                        {{item.name}}
                    </td></tr>
                {{/each}}
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="span9">
            {{outlet}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</script>
```

But the minute I moves this snippet to a .hbs file under templates directory, and include the following line in my application.js file,

```
#= require_tree ./templates
```

they fail with this error.

```
Assertion failed: You specified the templateName cms2/index for <CMS.IndexView:ember229>, but it did not exist.
```

I have tried to precompile then using two different Rubygems,

```
gem 'handlebars_assets'
```

and

```
gem 'ember-rails'
```

From what I read, those two gems are supposed to precompile all .hbs files and including the templates directory tree should fix this problem.

What am I missing?  Why isn't this working for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you turn on the Ember support in Handlebars Assets?

```
HandlebarsAssets::Config.ember = true
```

This will add the templates to the Ember.TEMPLATES namespace so they can be resolved.

Comment: buuda - Thanks for the tip.  

I hadn't added that, but adding that to environment.rb did not fix the error.  

Then I noticed that I was specifically adding handlebars-1.0.0 in my application.js.  I replaced it with #= require handlebars and that fixed the error.  

But now, the templates are not getting loaded, not even the application template.  

Ember.TEMPLATES says the following:

`Object {../cms2/templates/application: function, ../cms2/templates/index: function}
../cms2/templates/application: function (context, options) {
../cms2/templates/index: function (context, options) {`

Comment: I got this to work, but it feels like a hack.

I had to create two views and set the templates like this:

`window.CMS.IndexView = Ember.View.extend
  template: Ember.TEMPLATES['../cms2/index']`

That seems to work.  If I use templateName, it doesn't work.  I must be missing something obvious.

Thanks for the help anyway.